# How can I calculate the absolute value of a number in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have

```
<xsl:value-of select="DifferenceInDays" />
```

`DifferenceInDays` has a value that can be a negative or a positive number, I want to display its absolute value. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you could accept an answer?

Answer (score 36):

**In XPath 1.0 use the following expression**:

```
   $vNum*($vNum >=0) - $vNum*($vNum < 0)
```

In case this expression is embedded in an XSLT (XML) attribute, the `<` character must be escaped:

```
   $vNum*($vNum >=0) - $vNum*($vNum &lt; 0)
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) use the [`abs()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-abs) function**.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using the xpath abs function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="abs(DifferenceInDays)"/>
```

Comment: that's XPath 2.0, which basically does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the answers are complicating life way too much for XSLT 1.0 it's actually much simpler. Using the number formatting you can define a structure for Positive and Negative numbers, the default negative is `-0` however you can define your own.

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(DifferenceInDays,"0;0")'/>
```

The above code will show the absolute value of Difference in Days just by using the provided formatting function.

Comment: should work across as far as I'm aware. The format-number functionality is provided in the XSLT 1.0 spec.

Comment: Have you tested this with **any** one of them? If yes, in which one did it work?

Comment: tested and used in XSLT 1.0 processed using PHP. I used the same trick to format negative numbers to show them in brackets rather then with a negative number as that is the correct format for financial institutions.

Comment: You're not answering my question. PHP is not an XSLT processor. [Xalan-J](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHV), [Saxon 6.5](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHV/1) and libxslt are. This doesn't work in any one of the three.

Comment: it certainly works in LibXSLT (only processor that supports PHP) - just tried it now. And you can find information on how the format number works in W3 Schools, it's quite simple http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp

Comment: I *know* how format-number() works. And my information does not come from W3 Schools. However, it doesn't work on **my** libxslt - and if you'll click the links above, you'll see that it doesn't work in the other two processors either. Whether that's a correct interpretation of the XSLT 1.0 spec (which is actually the JDK 1.1 spec) is open to debate - but the fact remains that all three vendors thought so.

Comment: seems strange to be inconsistent within libxslt itself. I'll see weather there's another way to test this. I think it's very unlikely to be tied to something else other then the libxslt processor.

Comment: Also just for reference Saxon 9 from the links you provided - the example I gave also works. So most likely it was a misinterpretation of the spec compared to previous versions.

Comment: Yes, it does work in Saxon 9 - which is an **XSLT 2.0** processor, thus follows a different specification. In any case, if you want a simple solution using string manipulation that works universally, try `translate($number, '-', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

diffInDays * (1 - 2*(diffInDays &lt; 0))