# XPath Query to compare results are within numerical range

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>-100</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
            <location>
                <latitude>10</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>10</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
            <location>
                <latitude>10</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
<items>
```

I need to count the items with invalid latitude or longitude values.

Valid latitude is between -90 and 90. Valid longitude is between -180 and 180.

For ease of post, let's just try to get it to count latitude's greater than -90.

I have tried the following, none of which work:

```
count(//item[locations/location[number(latitude) &gt; -90])
count(//item[locations/location[number(latitude)] &gt; -90)
count(//item[locations/location/*[number(latitude) &gt; -90])
count(//item[locations/location/*[number(latitude)] &gt; -90)
count(//item[locations/location/*[number(name() = latitude)] &gt; -90)
count(//item[locations/location/*number([name() = latitude]) &gt; -90)
count(//item[number(deal/locations/location/*[name()=latitude]) &gt; -90])
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? If it is not, can anyone think of a neat workaround?

Thank You all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use less than, not greater than -  you want latitudes *less than* -90.

e.g. Running this xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <GoodItems>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[not(locations/location[number(latitude) &lt; -90 
                                                           or number(latitude) &gt; 90
                                                           or number(longitude) &lt; -180
                                                           or number(longitude) &gt; 180])])" />
    </GoodItems>
    <LatTooSmall>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[locations/location[number(latitude) &lt; -90]])" />
    </LatTooSmall>
    <LatTooBig>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[locations/location[number(latitude) &gt; 90]])" />
    </LatTooBig>
    <LongTooSmall>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[locations/location[number(longitude) &lt; -180]])" />
    </LongTooSmall>
    <LongTooBig>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[locations/location[number(longitude) &gt; 180]])" />
    </LongTooBig>
</xsl:template>
```

Against this test case xml document:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>10</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>-100</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>123</latitude>
                <longitude>10</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>0</latitude>
                <longitude>-200</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
    <item>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <latitude>0</latitude>
                <longitude>500</longitude>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </item>
</items>
```

Returns the following:

```
<GoodItems>1</GoodItems>
<LatTooSmall>1</LatTooSmall>
<LatTooBig>1</LatTooBig>
<LongTooSmall>1</LongTooSmall>
<LongTooBig>1</LongTooBig>
```

You could also use `abs()` if you have xslt 2, although Dimitre has a workaround in 1.0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804421/how-can-i-calculate-the-absolute-value-of-a-number-in-xslt)