# Positive number to negative

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, number-formatting

How to check number (decimal or whole number ) in XSLT .I want to convert it to Negative if it is positive number otherwise i have to keep as it is . I verfied in google and all i see is negative number to positive number,using XSLT version as 1.0. Please give some samples.

Take below samples:

```
<Books>
 <Book>
  <Name>NC</Name>
  <Price>100.50</Price>
 </Book>
 </Books>


<Books>
 <Book>
  <Name>NC</Name>
  <Price>-200</Price>
 </Book>
 </Books>
```

Negative number to Positive:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Price * (Price >= 0) - Price * not(Price >= 0)" />
```

I want convert any positive number to a negative one and if the number is already negative , I have to keep it as it is.

Comment: Please give me some samples first. Of your input XML, your current attempted XSLT code (the one where you tried to apply the method you found for transforming negative numbers to positive ones), the XML output you get and the one you expected. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804421/how-can-i-calculate-the-absolute-value-of-a-number-in-xslt) with `"-0;-0"` as the number format?

Comment: Muller, Please find the updated question.Sorry i fotgot to include examples

Answer (score 3):

How about doing it the simple way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- positive prices to negative -->
<xsl:template match="Price[. > 0]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="-."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your **input** example, corrected for well-formedness:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name>NC</Name>
        <Price>100.50</Price>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>NC</Name>
        <Price>-200</Price>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

produces the following **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Books>
   <Book>
      <Name>NC</Name>
      <Price>-100.5</Price>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <Name>NC</Name>
      <Price>-200</Price>
   </Book>
</Books>
```

**Note**: the wisdom of performing this operation eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the method by Dimitre Novatchev to find all positive numbers and then simply put a `-` around the whole expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="-(. * (. >= 0) - . *not(. >= 0))" />
```

Easy, isn't it? Remember that the `.` means the context node, in this case always a `Price` element.

**EDIT**: Actually, this works, too:

```
<xsl:value-of select=". * not(. >= 0) - . *(. >= 0)" />
```

But then it is (even) less obvious what the code does, in my opinion.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Price">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="-(. * (. >= 0) - . *not(. >= 0))" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

Assuming the following input, where both negative and positive numbers are present:

```
<Books>
  <Price>100.50</Price>
  <Price>-133.50</Price>
  <Price>999</Price>
  <Price>-183</Price>
</Books>
```

**XML Output**

As you can see, negative numbers are what they were, positive ones are negative now.

```
<Books>
   <Price>-100.5</Price>
   <Price>-133.5</Price>
   <Price>-999</Price>
   <Price>-183</Price>
</Books>
```